# Java Cache Implementation in a web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, caching, guava, ehcache

I have a web application in which for each user I am creating a file and Storing the file in session as stream for certain operation to be performed after that and also I don't want to load the huge file again and again to perform some operations.

I want store the file in a cache instead of relying on the session for some reasons. After few research, I found lot of cache implementations which is getting complex and complex.

Which of the below cache implementations will be suitable for this scenario?

1. LRU
2. Time based(Expiry).

A simple LRU cache using ConcurrentHashMap is enough for my requirement? Is there any way to create LRU cache with expiry time?

Comment: Guava's `Cache` supports expiration a specified amount of time after the most recent access.

Comment: [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained), and [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org) are all robust solutions ([benchmarks](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks)).

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman. I heard about Guava. I am just thinking Do I need to proceed with an open source library or Just to build a simple LRU cache using ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: You can't actually write a LRU cache with ConcurrentHashMap, I believe, so your second option isn't possible.